# ResultSet make an error

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc

hello i have a problem with this resultset.

```
    public ResultSet seleccionar(String id, String pass) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement stmt;

     String consulta = "SELECT iduser from personas ";
         consulta+= " WHERE nombre=?";
         consulta+= " AND pass= ?";


     objetoConexion = Conexion.getInstance().getConnection();
     stmt = objetoConexion.prepareStatement(consulta);
          stmt.setString(1,id);
          stmt.setString(2,pass);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);

    rs.first();
     return rs;
```

this is my error

.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?   AND pass= ?' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a space before AND.

```
String consulta = "SELECT iduser from personas ";
         consulta+= " WHERE nombre='?";
         consulta+= "' AND pass='?'";
```

Comment: I have the same error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? AND pass= ?'

Comment: Try now, maybe its an error due to the quotes as strings/varchar needs quotes in SELECT queries

Answer (score 0):

You need to check you spaces on your String consulta.

Have you considered using a [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and logging your SQL statements to the console so you can see what the queries look like?